# Visual Studio 2022 - Git - Remote hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022

I'm new to Git, and I have a code base that I've been working on, on my computer, for several months. I created a GitHub repository for it, and I've tried off and on to push my code to GitHub, but it has never worked properly. There are many, many commits now, and 10,166 files to push, so I can appreciate the fact that there's probably too much to push at once.

I've done searches online and they all talk about issuing git config commands at the command line to "fix" the issue. My problem is, I'm in Visual Studio 2022. When I go to a command line (or terminal, or Powershell), and type 'git', I get a message telling me it's an unknown command.

My issue is just going to get worse as my repository grows. Can someone please tell me how I can resolve this issue if I'm pushing from Visual Studio 2022?

Answer (score 1):

Try to install git from https://git-scm.com/download/win
then you should have git command working in cmd and powershell